# Ruby Hash - sort by value and print keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

This is my hash.

```
=> {"f11"=>1, "f12"=>3, "f13"=>3, "f07"=>5, "f10"=>1}
```

I'd like to sort by the values largest to smallest and then make an array out of the keys.

```
=> ["f07", "f12", "f13", "f11", "f10"]
```

Comment: I guess you also want to order the keys when values are the same ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a one-liner for you (I love ruby!):

```
h.keys.sort {|a, b| h[b] <=> h[a]}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Hash has the Enumerable module mixed in which provides us with methods like sort and sort_by.In this situation we can use sort_by to get a collection by order of values.

```
 h={"f11"=>1, "f12"=>3, "f13"=>3, "f07"=>5, "f10"=>1} 
 h.sort_by{ |key, value| -value }  
 => [["f07", 5], ["f12", 3], ["f13", 3], ["f11", 1], ["f10", 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Even shorter!:

```
h.keys.sort_by{|a| h[a]}.reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {"f11"=>1, "f12"=>3, "f13"=>3, "f07"=>5, "f10"=>1}
b = Hash[a.sort_by{|k,v| v}]
puts b.keys.reverse
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I put the keys in an Array?

Comment: calling keys on a hash returns an array of keys, so in this case b.keys is returning an array iteself which is reversed since you wanted to sort values in descending order